# PHP mysql transaction with try catch error handling

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code for the transaction in php. But some queries are committed and some are not committed.

I need complete mysql php transaction handling code.

```
 try {
    require_once './DB/dbConnect.php';
    $conn->autocommit(FALSE);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `grn_items` WHERE grn_no ='" . $Doc . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        $result->free();
        return $conn->error;
        //throw new Exception($conn->error);
    }
   $sq3 = "UPDATE `grn` SET `editBy` = '" . $editBy . "' ,grnAmount ='" .             
   $total . "'    WHERE grnNo ='" . $Doc . "'";
    $result3 = $conn->query($sq3);

    if (!$result3) {
        $result3->free();
        return $conn->error;
        //throw new Exception($conn->error);
    }
    $conn->commit();
    $conn->autocommit(TRUE);
    $conn->close();
    return "success";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $conn->rollback();
    $conn->autocommit(TRUE);
    return $ex;
}
```

Comment: _I need complete mysql php transaction handling code_ and I need the lottery number so I can win El Gordo, if you have those I will rewrite your code for you. _Seems a fair trade to me_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmmm, didn't know stackoverflow can be so humorous sometimes. :)

Comment: Who on earth Upvoted this question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote This question most certainly does not warrant an UV

Comment: Actually it would be uneful to see what is actually in the `dbConnect.php` can you add that to your question

Comment: @user1735921 You gota add a bit of humour, otherwise questions like this would just drive you to drink

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Also: You can use `catch (Exception $ex)` but PDO actually throws a `PDOException` so it would be better to use `catch (PDOException $ex) {} catch (Exception $ex) {}`

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
require_once './DB/dbConnect.php';
```

should be outside try and catch, so it should be

```
require_once './DB/dbConnect.php';
 try {

    $conn->autocommit(FALSE);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `grn_items` WHERE grn_no ='" . $Doc . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        $result->free();
        return $conn->error;
        //throw new Exception($conn->error);
    }
   $sq3 = "UPDATE `grn` SET `editBy` = '" . $editBy . "' ,grnAmount ='" .             
   $total . "'    WHERE grnNo ='" . $Doc . "'";
    $result3 = $conn->query($sq3);

    if (!$result3) {
        $result3->free();
        return $conn->error;
        //throw new Exception($conn->error);
    }
    $conn->commit();
    $conn->autocommit(TRUE);
    $conn->close();
    return "success";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $conn->rollback();
    $conn->autocommit(TRUE);
    return $ex;
}
```

because your variable `$conn` is coming from there.

Comment: I would love to know why you think this would make any difference

Comment: because $conn is defined in dbConnect.php, if any exception occurs in try, $conn would be undefined hence leading to error.

Comment: If any exception was thrown in `dbConnect` then the code would jump straight to the `catch()` and NO SQL CODE **or any other code would be executed at all** ___FACEPALM___